# How do I set some script in the <head> section on a page?

Tags: 7, javascript

I solved some question on field type generation and learned how to render my custom field.
Now, I need to use an accessible audioplayer to play my songs. In my custom field formatter view function I set item_output to render this custom field in an unordered list. Each item of this list is a link that calls a javascript function that plays automatically the song.
Unfortunately, to use this player, I must set some script in header section of my page, and style css for this player.
So, I need to set these scripts on ly in a page that displays this field. There is a way? Maybe in $element array returned from field formatter view function?
I hope you can understand me, my english is very bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [drupal_add_js](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7.x) can solve your probleme.
You can try this in custom module:

```
function my_module_init() {
     drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME') .'/my_file.js',
        array('type' => 'file', 'scope' => 'header', 'weight' => 1000)
      );
}
```

Look at this [documention](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/javascript-api/adding-javascript-to-your-theme-or-module) for use this function in diffrent way.